# Android Material Design Components Sample

Tags: android, progress-bar

I'm new at material design. I'm working on some projects and I want to use the material design. But I cannot find any source or sample for components. Is there any code sample (especially animated circle loader)?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tens (if not hundreds) samples regarding ways to implement Material Design, some of 'em even described how you could make it work for older versions of Android.

This [blog post](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/) by Google's own Chris Banes regarding AppCompat v21 is a good place to start when you're also working on Android versions lower than Lollipop.

While [this](http://chris.banes.me/2014/07/04/palette-preview/), still from Mr. Banes, thoroughly describe one of Lollipop's most famed API, `Palette`.

Moving on, [this blog post](https://www.google.co.id/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCQQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftrickyandroid.com%2Fsimple-ripple-reveal-elevation-tutorial%2F&ei=2K5sVKTmBKbKmAXa3YHQCg&usg=AFQjCNHq0RkjtmhwU5ch2uvKKpkpCR47CA&sig2=xY9GQnRHoHHGK_G8mV022Q&bvm=bv.80120444,d.dGY) would help you started with those shiny round buttons (or FABs) and, as a bonus, a trick to apply ripple effect to it.

I think those three links should be more than enough to get you started making Material apps - I've built mine and those three were my first guides. Sadly though, I can't find one that matches exactly with your Dribbble link. Then again, I doubt a widget such as those exists today. I've been wrong before though. :)

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

**Learn more:**

Modular and customizable Material Design UI components for Android

**Git link:**
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android

**Playstore link:**
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.materialdesign.catalog